# link_to under show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, link-to

How can I convert these links and make them work in the show view?

I use the below button set in the index view but wanting to move these links under show view. I tried variations and different ways but can't get them to work.

The user has nested addresses and business profiles, I'm also trying to link over to edit and delete.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit User', edit_users_main_path(users_main), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'User Address', users_main_contacts_path(users_main), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'User Business', users_main_businesses_path(users_main), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'Delete User', users_main, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn" %>
```

Comment: What's the error when you tried moving it to `show`? Is `users_main` available to `show`?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `users_main'

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was suspecting for. You need to define the `users_main` varibale. Check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37126432/1047207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that what you are expecting in `users_main`, however, I assume it should be an user object. You need to define it in `show` action show that you can use it in respective view.

```
# Controller
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # just an example to define your instance varibale
  ...
  ...
end
```

Then use same instance variable in the view

```
# View
...
...

<%= link_to 'Edit User', edit_users_main_path(@user), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'User Address', users_main_contacts_path(@user), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'User Business', users_main_businesses_path(@user), class: "btn" %>
<%= link_to 'Delete User', @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn" %>

...
```

Comment: Thanks I was missing the @user part on my link_to